# rmarkdown::render_site() Error in rmarkdown::render_site() : No site generator found

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to knit together 3 files using this example: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html

My files all share the same directory, which has been set in the RStudio build options.  I literally copied the YML from the examples with my own file names.  Even if I copy the examples directly, I get the same error.

I even ran the site_generator function from the RMarkdown Github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/render_site.R#L157

I noticed there are options for custom generators, which I do not want.  All I would like to do is be able to knit together several markdown files into a single webpage and then create a navbar with tabs for each page/section.

Comment: Happened to me when I had not yet added an `index.Rmd`.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error when attempting to build with an incorrectly named YAML config file. Specifically, the RStudio build option for a website requires that the config file be called `_site.yml`.

Verify that this file exists and that you're using the extension `.yml` rather than `.yaml` (even though [the latter is preferred](http://www.yaml.org/faq.html)).

Answer (score 7):

What helped for me was putting the line `site: bookdown::bookdown_site` back to `index.Rmd`.

Comment: This also worked for me. It goes above the beginning of the `output:` section

Answer (score 3):

lord, my issue was that i didn't set my working directly to where my _site.yml file and index.Rmd files are stored - the little things!

Comment: seems like a comment

Comment: @StupidWolf agreed that this is written as more of a comment but this is ultimately what my issue was and led me to finding a fix. Would it be appropriate to edit this existing answer with more detail or add a new answer?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error using this steps.

1-) RStudio-Tools-InstallPackages 
2-) Install From should be CRAN Repository.
3-) write this command -->  install.packages("install.packages("rmarkdown")")
4-) Click Install

And problem has gone... And this is output.

[image]

Comment: By the way, if you're using Linux, you should be root mode.

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears when there is a format issue in the yaml section of index.Rmd.

In my case, I encountered the error when the opening "---" in index.Rmd had a couple of white spaces "    ---".

If you are having this problem, I would recommend knitting index.Rmd by itself (not building the book) before trying anything more drastic.

Another instance of this problem can occur when recycling an old Bookdown project and making it a Quarto book. If the `.Rproj` file has `BuildType: Website`, removing that line will fix the issue.

Comment: Somehow I deleted the leading `---` in my yaml of index.rmd, which leads to similar problems!