# Error in rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = "UTF-8") : No site generator found.""

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

I try to get started with **bookdown** in **RStudio**. I downloaded bookdown-minimal-master. After loading `index.Rmd` I click the button Build Book. Then I get the error message

`Error in rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = "UTF-8") :    No site generator found.`

What is going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmarkdown::render\_site() Error in rmarkdown::render\_site() : No site generator found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488681/rmarkdownrender-site-error-in-rmarkdownrender-site-no-site-generator-f)